How can a container change the display of a child in the default slots?
I have a vue playground.
The container component needs to be able to control the display status of an unknown number of children in the default slot.
I assume the child components will need to hold a property or have some way of identifying themselves to their container.
How can the container change the display property of one of the components in the default slot?
NOTE: there is a related question at How can a container change the CSS display property of a child in the default slots? with a focus on using CSS to resolve the same issue.
App.vue
<script setup>
import Container from './Container.vue'
import ChildA from './ChildA.vue'
import ChildB from './ChildB.vue'
</script>

<template>
    <Container>
        <ChildA />
        <ChildB />
    </Container>
</template>

Container.vue
<script setup>
import { useSlots, useAttrs, onMounted} from 'vue'

const slots = useSlots()

function logSlots(where) {
  console.log( `${where} slots`, slots )
  const children = slots.default()
  console.log( `${where} slots children`, children.length, children )
}

logSlots("setup")

function changeDisplay(whichChild, show) {
  console.log( "change display", whichChild, show)
  // how can I know I am accessing child a?
  // what goes here?
}

onMounted( () => {
  logSlots("onMounted")
})
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="logSlots('button')">log slots</button>
  <button @click="changeDisplay('child a', false)">Hide Child A</button>
  <button @click="changeDisplay('child a', true)">Show Child A</button>

  <slot />
</template>

ChildA.vue
<script setup>
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    ChildA
  </div>
</template>

ChildB.vue
<script setup>
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    ChildB
  </div>
</template>


This requires to use render function, then you can process the props of vnodes. Consider explaining your case further, it's said "unknown number of children in the default slot" but the container is hardcoded for a and b. If there's finite amount of children, it could use named slots instead, this is a common case for them

Pretend there were components ChildC ... Child, that I created the components for them and added them as well. I just didn't want to create another X number of components as that would be needlessly redundant. I cannot use named slots because I do not know how many children there are. How can I use the render function to solve my problem?

"how many children there are" - I mean that you currently hardcoded "Hide Child A", and the container may need to be aware of all of them to distinguish between them any way. A possible solution may depend on a specific case rather than A/B abstraction, consider explaining it. Render function would be something like () => context.slots.default().map(vnode => cloneVNode(vnode, { style: { display: isHidden ? 'none' : null } }))

I did hardcode "Hide Child A". Pretend that there was a way for me to dynamically create "Hide Child X" buttons for all of the children in the default slot of Container. To do so for a simple example, would be cumbersome and needlessly redundant. In that render function, I do not see a way to identify what child node is being changed to hidden. It looks like function would change every child node to hidden and it needs to be targeted.

What you describe means that the structure of slot vnodes should affect the container's state, i.e. render function contains side effect, this is a bad practice at least, particularly because this can result in infinite loop. For comps that are identified by their names and not some id prop this could be achieved with something like let childKeys = context.slots.default().map(vnode => vnode.type?.name).filter(Boolean) in render fn, then keys in container state are synced with the ones from childKeys, and vnodes can receive updated style.display like in the previous comment

I didn't see this implemented anywhere in third-party libs and it looks troublesome to me. It would be cleaner to use dom to update children style. Consider updating the question with your case explained in details if you're interested in more conventional approaches to what you want to achieve in the end.

Seems strange that there isn't a way to go from slots.default()[0] to either the HTML element of the child or the vue component of the child. I wonder why that is.

"vue component of the child" - do you mean component instance? There's no html element at the point when slot vnode is processed in render function, vnode is a blueprint for a component or element to be rendered. If you want to deal with the visibility of dom elements then this needs to be done in lifecycle hooks when child comps are already rendered

What about after everything is rendered? Can you get to a component instance via slots.default()[0], for example?

Vnodes can contain internal stuff like instancess iirc, but this isn't how it works officially, this isn't what they are for. But you can extend them and add your own ref to access instances they represent, "ref" isn't a prop but cloneVNode seems to handle it in the 2nd arg, would be something likecloneVNode(vnode, { ref: arrayOfRefs[i] }. Didn't test it but expect to work

@EstusFlask somehow I've managed that work through array of refs (before seeing your comment), also I've used h and noticed that it uses cloneVNode internally for vnodes passed as a component: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78387331/how-can-i-call-an-exposed-function-of-a-vue-component-in-a-default-slot/78389222#78389222

@AlexanderNenashev This isn't documented https://vuejs.org/api/render-function.html#h , good to know

@EstusFlask inside h there's some code like if(isVNode(vnode)) cloneVNode(vnode, ...). do you think it's bad to use h? i guess it's not possible to remove this logic from h only without breaking something in Vue itself

@AlexanderNenashev Looks like reliable undocumented behaviour based on the implementation. I'd use h myself and stick to cloneVNode in teamwork to avoid  uncertainty

You can hide the default slot's children either by name or reference (also by index (not in the code)):
VUE SFC PLAYGROUND
<script setup>
import { useSlots, reactive} from 'vue';
import ChildA from './ChildA.vue'
import ChildB from './ChildB.vue'
const slots = useSlots();
const slotted = () => slots.default().map(vnode => hide.has(vnode.type.name) ? null : vnode);
const slotted2 = () => slots.default().map(vnode => hide.has(vnode.type) ? null : vnode);

const hide = reactive(new Set);


function changeDisplay(whichChild) {
  hide.has(whichChild) ? hide.delete(whichChild) : hide.add(whichChild);
}

</script>

<template>
  <button @click="changeDisplay('ChildA')">Toggle Child A</button>
  <button @click="changeDisplay('ChildB')">Toggle Child B</button>
  <slotted />
  <button @click="changeDisplay(ChildA)">Toggle Child A</button>
  <button @click="changeDisplay(ChildB)">Toggle Child B</button>
  <slotted2 />
</template>

A dynamic example:
VUE SFC PLAYGROUND

I like this technique. It will be useful to me moving forward. However, I was hoping to manipulate the CSS display property of the child components to resolve the issue. I may need to manipulate other CSS properties with the same technique -- assuming one exists. Perhaps, based on all of the comments, this is not possible.

Is this technique based on documented behavior? Or is it based on undocumented behavior which should not be relied upon?

@EricG I believe it's totally reliable and documented : https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function

@EricG it's possible with deep selectors: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#deep-selectors

I created another question, making the CSS requirement explicit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78390360/how-can-a-container-change-the-css-display-property-of-a-child-in-the-default-sl
