How can I call an exposed function of a vue component in a default slot?
I have a vue playground.
ChildA and ChildB both expose a function called interfaceFunction.
I can call this function from App by getting a reference to the component. With the reference, I can call the function directly.
I would like Container to be able to call this function of the children in its default slot. How can Container get a reference to the components and call the function?
App.vue
<script setup>
import { ref} from 'vue'

import Container from './Container.vue'
import ChildA from './ChildA.vue'
import ChildB from './ChildB.vue'

const childa = ref(null)

function callInterfaceFunction() {
    childa.value.interfaceFunction()
}
</script>

<template>
    <button @click="callInterfaceFunction">Call from App</button>

    <Container>
        <ChildA ref="childa"/>
        <ChildB />
    </Container>
</template>

Container.vue
<script setup>
import { useSlots} from 'vue'

const slots = useSlots()

function callInterfaceFunction() {
  const children = slots.default()

  for ( const child of children ) {
    child.interfaceFunction()
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="callInterfaceFunction">Call from Container</button>

  <slot />
</template>

ChildA.vue
<script setup>

function interfaceFunction() {
  console.log( "Called interfaceFunction A" )
}

defineExpose({ interfaceFunction })
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    ChildA
  </div>
</template>

ChildB.vue
<script setup>

function interfaceFunction() {
  console.log( "Called interfaceFunction A" )
}

defineExpose({ interfaceFunction })
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    ChildB
  </div>
</template>


You just add refs to your slot's vnodes:
NOTE: you could want to change h to cloneVNode since using h seems not documented yet: https://github.com/vuejs/docs/issues/2834
VUE SFC PLAYGROUND
<script setup>
import { useSlots, ref, h} from 'vue'

const slots = useSlots();
let $children;
const slotted = () => ($children = [], slots.default().map((vnode, i) => h(vnode, {ref: $children[i] ??= ref()})));

function callInterfaceFunction(){
  $children.forEach(({value: child}) => child.interfaceFunction());
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="callInterfaceFunction">Call from Container</button>
  <slotted/>
</template>

A more generic approach needs to recursively traverse nodes to collect refs (though this doesn't handle situation of existing refs and probably slots, you could improve yourself). This allows to wrap slotted components, for example render them conditionally:
VUE SFC PLAYGROUND
<script setup>
import { useSlots, ref, h} from 'vue'

const slots = useSlots();
let $children;
const traverse = vnode => {
  vnode = h(vnode, {ref: $children[$children.length] ??= ref()});
  vnode.children = vnode.children?.map(traverse);
  return vnode;
};
const slotted = () => ($children = [], slots.default().map(traverse));

function callInterfaceFunction(){
  $children.forEach(({value:child}) => child.interfaceFunction?.());
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="callInterfaceFunction">Call from Container</button>
  <slotted/>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

import Container from './Container.vue'
import ChildA from './ChildA.vue'
import ChildB from './ChildB.vue'

const childa = ref(null)

const swapped = ref(false);

function callInterfaceFunction() {
    childa.value?.interfaceFunction()
}
</script>

<template>
    <button @click="callInterfaceFunction">Call from App</button>

    <Container>
        <template v-if="!swapped"><ChildA ref="childa"/><ChildB/></template>
        <template v-else="swapped"><ChildB/><ChildA ref="childa"/></template>
    </Container>
    <button @click="swapped = !swapped">Swap</button>
</template>

